# Id Count as one with in one hour if repeated based on event name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create table #test (Id int,Event_name varchar(20),Dates datetime2)
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates)
values (100,'Booked date','2017-07-22 10:00:00.0000000')
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates)
values (100,'Booked date','2017-07-22 10:30:00.0000000')
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates)
values (100,'Booked date','2017-07-22 11:30:00.0000000')
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates)
values (100,'Booked slot',  '2017-07-22 10:10:00.0000000')
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates)
values (100,'Booked slot',  '2017-07-22 10:20:00.0000000')
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates)
values (101,'blue', '2017-06-22 12:11:00.0000000')
```

I am trying to find the count of Events that occurred in an hour, so the result set would look like this:

```
 Id |Event_name|DateS  |  Count
------------------------------------
100|Booked date|7/22/2017 10:00 |1 
100|Booked slot|7/22/2017 10:10 |1 
100|Booked slot|7/22/2017 10:20 |NULL 
100|Booked date|7/22/2017 10:30 |NULL
100|Booked date|7/22/2017 11:30 |1
101|blue       |6/22/2017 12:11 |1
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: That doesn't look like Oracle code to me.

Comment: The question is not clear, when to return NULL and when to 1?

Comment: If any id repeated with in one hour count should be one only,Ex:Id 100 with event name Booked Date repeated 10:00 and 10:20 and 10:30 this 3 rows repeating in one hour only so we need to take count 1 only, if i add 1 hour to 10:00, 11:00 will come between this all rows should be NULL

Comment: Tip: A single `insert` statement can include multiple rows in the `values` clause: `insert into #test ( Id, Event_name, Dates ) 
values ( 100, 'Booked date', '2017-07-22 10:00:00.0000000' ), 
( 100, 'Booked date', '2017-07-22 10:30:00.0000000' ), ...;`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I assumed you wanted to round the hour up if it was a nanosecond past the hour. Example: 10:00:01 would be considered in the 11th hour.

```
create table #test (Id int,Event_name varchar(20),Dates datetime2) 
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates) 
values (100,'Booked date','2017-07-22 10:00:00.0000000') 
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates) 
values (100,'Booked date','2017-07-22 10:30:00.0000000') 
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates) 
values (100,'Booked date','2017-07-22 11:30:00.0000000') 
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates) 
values (100,'Booked slot','2017-07-22 10:10:00.0000000') 
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates) 
values (100,'Booked slot', '2017-07-22 10:20:00.0000000') 
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates) 
values (101,'blue', '2017-06-22 12:11:00.0000000')
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates) 
values (100,'Booked date','2017-07-22 11:25:00.0000000') 
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates) 
values (100,'Booked date','2017-07-22 12:25:00.0000000') 
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates) 
values (100,'Booked date','2017-07-22 12:26:00.0000000') 
insert into #test(Id,Event_name,Dates) 
values (100,'Booked date','2017-07-22 12:25:00.0001000') 

SELECT Id,Event_name,Dates,
     --Get row number to determine if value of count should be NULL
     CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id,[Year],[Month],[Date],
     [Hour] 
    ORDER BY Id,[Year],[Month],[Date],[Hour],[Minute],[Seconds],
    [Nanoseconds]) = 1
    THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS 'Count' 
    FROM (SELECT Id,Event_name,Dates,DATEPART(yy,Dates) 'Year',
        DATEPART(m,Dates) 'Month',DATEPART(d,Dates) 'Date', 
        DATEPART(hh,Dates) 'Hour',DATEPART(mi,Dates) 'Minute',
        DATEPART(s,Dates) 'Seconds', DATEPART(ns,Dates) 'Nanoseconds'
  FROM #test) AS t

drop table #test
```

Comment: Thanks for your Response Jason,but its not giving proper out put,for example (100,'Booked date','2017-07-22 10:00:00.0000000') this id on this date time 10:00 if i add one hour 11:00 will come between 10:00 and 11:00 how many times this id will come we need to consider count 1 only,if same id repeated after one hour  then we need to consider one more count, i think this will help you